# looking for a lightweight wysiwyg editor

Tags: jquery, editor, wysiwyg

i searched the web for a lightweight (online) wysiwyg editor and tried several ones - 
the good ones were just all too bloated to me and the light ones where missing features.

is there a good lightweight editor (app. 70kb maximum) which supports also table editing?

Comment: WYSIWYG *text* editor, I'm assuming?

Comment: I assumed WYSIWYG html editor

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best WYSIWYG Editor for use with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141073/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-for-use-with-jquery)

Comment: I think you are very unlikely to find an editor that small that supports table editing. The code needed just to work around browser bugs is almost that size, and table editing is a non-trivial feature.

Answer (score 2):

I gave TinyMCE some extensive testing with jQuery and found it to be quite excellent and you can make it very small / light. Only limitation is that it does not work well with jQuery UI library.

Other editors I compared it with are YUI Editor and CKeditor. TinyMCE was by far the most easy to use. CKeditor now has licensing restrictions which might limit you depending on how you're using it.

I recommend using server-side GZip compression and combine and minify files where you can.

Comment: I agree TinyMCE is pretty easy to use. The only thing I didn't like about it was the large number of files which end up in your project

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[(F)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fckeditor/)[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [TinyMce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) may look bloated at first glance, but they are actually very good customizeable. Read: you can just **hide** all of those "unnecessary" features.</strike>

**Edit** nevermind, I missed the jQuery part. At least, every decent editor should give you the ability to **hide** the "unnecessary" features.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the TinyMCE Copressor (available for JSP, PHP, .NET and ColdFusion)
You´ll get a very small editor. That loads even faster, because you can enable only a few plugins. That keeps it small and handy.

MaikL